# Ranking a vector containing ties

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I rank a vector such that the ties are replaced by their middle ranks. For example, `{1, 2, 2, 3}`. I want to rank this vector but the ties must be replaced by their mid-rank; i.e., given `{1, 2, 2, 3}`, I want to get the vector `{1, 2.5, 2.5, 4}`. Does there exist any fast command or function to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
list = {1, 2, 2, 3};

(Ordering@Ordering@# + Reverse@Ordering@Ordering@Reverse@#)/2 &@list
```

> {1, 5/2, 5/2, 4}

As requested, here as a function:

```
rank[list_] := (Ordering@Ordering@list + Reverse@Ordering@Ordering@Reverse@list)/2
```

Comment: Nice, ~4x more faster than mine!

Comment: @IstvánZachar Thanks! Indeed, `Ordering` is a much underestimated function with lots of hidden power. It is very useful for fast, partial sorts, for instance.

Comment: @ S.C. de Vries: Can you increase its speed by putting in the form of proper function named Rank[x_]:= ?

Comment: @AbdulHaq I've added a function definition. As far as I could see there is so speed increase (not that I expected it).

Comment: That's pretty darn clever. +1

Answer (score 6):

Both methods assume continuous sublists of identical elements, i.e., an already sorted vector. `Gather` is ~10x faster than `Union` for larger lists.

```
x = {1, 2, 2, 3};
f1[x_] := x /. (# -> Mean @ Flatten@Position[x, #] & /@ Union@x);
f2[x_] := 
  Module[{i = 1}, x /. ((First @ # -> (i + (i = i + Length @ #) - 1)/2) & /@ Gather@x)];

{f1@x, f2@x}
```

> ```
>  {{1, 5/2, 5/2, 4}, {1, 5/2, 5/2, 4}}
> ```

```
y = Sort@RandomInteger[{0, 100}, {100000}];
AbsoluteTiming[r1 = f1@y;]
AbsoluteTiming[r2 = f2@y;]
r1 === r2
```

> ```
> {2.090404, Null}
> {0.327601, Null}
> True
> ```

Comment: @ István Zachar: Indeed both functions are acceptable depending on time constraints. I really appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 1):

```
Statistics`Library`GetDataRankings[{1, 2, 2, 3}]
```

> {1, 5/2, 5/2, 4}

This is slower than Istvan's `f2` but faster than his `f1`. @Sjoerd's `rank` is the fastest of the four. With

```
gdr = Statistics`Library`GetDataRankings
```

and using Istvan's setup for timings:

```
y = Sort@RandomInteger[{0, 100}, {1000000}];
t1 = First@AbsoluteTiming[r1 = f1 @ y;]; (* istvan's answer *)
t2 = First@AbsoluteTiming[r2 = f2 @ y;]; (* istvan's answer *)
t3 = First@AbsoluteTiming[r3 = gdr @ y;];
t4 = First@AbsoluteTiming[r4 = rank@y;]; (* sjoerd's answer *)

r1 === r2 === r3 === r4
```

> True

```
Grid[Transpose@SortBy[Transpose[{{"f1", "f2", "gdr", "rank"}, {t1, t2, t3, t4}}], Last], 
   Dividers -> All]
```

> $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
> \hline
>  \text{rank} & \text{f2} & \text{gdr} & \text{f1} \\
> \hline
>  0.687670 & 1.440178 & 3.297210 & 8.324320 \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$