# How to get the ranked order

Tags: sorting

```
data = {33, 6, 10};
Ordering[data]
(* {2, 3, 1} *)
```

What I really want is, 
3 for 33, as it is the 3rd, if sorted;
1 for 6, as it is the 1st, if sorted;
and
2 for 10, as it is the 2nd, if sorted;
so I want this returned:

```
(* {3,1,2} *)
```

How to do that?
I checked the help page for `Order` and `Sort`, which is unless.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56868/57 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33151/ranking-a-vector-containing-ties

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Ordering @ Ordering @ data
```

> {3,1,2}

Also:

```
Statistics`Library`GetDataRankings[data]
Nest[Ordering, data, 2]
Composition[Ordering, Ordering][data]
```

all give

> {3,1,2}

Comment: This seemed to easy, which should be an example in the help page! Thanks!

Comment: @ChenStatsYu, i agree...