# Rank Transformation of an Array

Tags: functions, data

Is there a built in function which rank transforms an array of data? By rank transformation I mean

```
data = {2.4,5,1,6,7,10,2}
Rank[data]={3,4,1,5,6,7,2}
```

where each value in `data` is assigned a rank from minimum to maximum where the lowest value in `data` is assigned the value of 1, the next highest value is assigned the value of 2, ect. 
`Ordering[]` does not accomplish this as we obtain

```
Ordering[data]
{3,7,1,2,4,5,6}
```

Edit 1: As Carl pointed out, I need to express what I want to happen in the case of a tied ranking. Ultimately, I want to use this rank transformation in the context of the definition of Spearman's Rho function where

```
Covariance[Transpose[{Rank[X],Rank[Y]}]/(
StandardDeviation[Rank[X]]*StandardDeviation[Rank[Y]])
```

should equal

```
SpearmanRho[Transpose[{X,Y}]][[1,2]]
```

where X and Y are equally lengthed arrays of data.

Comment: What do you want to return when there are ties?

Comment: Ah, great question. Give me a moment to respond in this comment with an edit.

Comment: I've actually edited the question to address your point Carl.

Comment: closely related / possible duplicate: [How to get the ranked order](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67447/125)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Statistics`Library`GetDataRankings[{2.4, 5, 1, 6, 7, 10, 2}]
```

> {3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 7, 2}

This gives the same result as `Ordering@Ordering@#&` if there are no ties in the input data.

If input data has ties:

```
Statistics`Library`GetDataRankings[{1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5}]
```

> {1, 7/2, 7/2, 7/2, 7/2, 7, 7, 7, 9, 10}

It is faster than `Ordering@Ordering@#&` but slower than Henrik Schumacher's `Ranking`:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 1000000];
a = Ranking[data]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.18

```
b = Ordering[Ordering[data]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.307

```
c = Statistics`Library`GetDataRankings[data]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.226

```
a == b == c
```

> True

A slightly faster alternative (still slower than `Ranking`):

```
ranks = Module[{r = Range@Length@#, o = Ordering@#}, Permute[r, o]] &;
d = ranks @ data; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.203

```
a == b == c == d
```

> True

Answer (score 5):

What about this?

```
Ordering[Ordering[data]]
```

> {3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 7, 2}

Since `Ordering` is the bottleneck, here a variant that needs only one call to `Ordering`:

```
Ranking[data_] := Module[{a},
  a = Range[Length[data]];
  a[[Ordering[data]]] = a;
  a
  ]
```

Comparison:

```
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 1000000];
a = Ranking[data]; // RepeatedTiming // First
b = Ordering[Ordering[data]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
a == b
```

> 0.13
>
> 0.234
>
> True

Comment: Brilliant! This does it. Thanks very much.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Carl Woll brought up a great point with regards to tied rankings. I thought I'd ping you in this comment in case you wanted to address it. For my purposes, I don't believe there are ties in my dataset of interest, so your solution still holds.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my own question with a constructed function which does the job:

```
Rank[x_]:=Flatten[Table[Position[Sort[x], x[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[x]}]]
```

`Ordering[]` gives the sort of inverse of the above function where you get the position of the unsorted data with respect to the sorted data. Here, the Rank function gets the position of the sorted data with respect to the unsorted data.