# How to build a ranking matrix

Tags: matrix, dataset, associations

I have the following `Association`:

```
dt =
  <|"fra" -> <|"19" -> 1.3, "20" -> 0.5, "21" -> 2.2, "22" -> 6.4|>,
   "gre" -> <|"19" -> 0.5, "20" -> -1.3, "21" -> 0.6, "22" -> 9.5|>,
   "ita" -> <|"19" -> 0.7, "20" -> -0.2, "21" -> 2.0, "22" -> 9.2|>,
   "por" -> <|"19" -> 0.3, "20" -> -0.1, "21" -> 0.9, "22" -> 8.4|>,
   "spa" -> <|"19" -> 0.8, "20" -> -0.4, "21" -> 3.1, "22" -> Missing[_]|>|>;

dt // Dataset
```

[image]

The values should be replaced by their corresponding ranks in ascending order.
For example, in the first column `por` has rank 1 and `fra` has rank 5.

```
yr = Keys[First @ dt];

dt = Sort /@ Transpose[dt];

dt = 
  Table[Map[Module[{i = 0}, {yr[[n]], If[MatchQ[#, _Missing], Missing[_], ++i]} &]] @ dt[[n]], {n, Range @ Length @ dt}];

dt = dt /. Association -> List /. Rule[a_, {b_, c_}] :> {a, b -> c};

GroupBy[Flatten[dt, 1], First -> Rest, Association] // SortBy[Last] // Dataset
```

[image]

These ugly lines did what I want, but I am looking for a more functional and elegant way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ClearAll[ranks, colRanks]

ranks = Map[
  Apply[AssociationThread] @*
  Through @* {Keys, Ordering @* Ordering} @*
  DeleteMissing];

colRanks = Transpose @* ranks @* Transpose @* Dataset;


colRanks @ dt
```

[image]

```
SortBy[Key @ "19"] @ colRanks @ dt
```

[image]

#### Update:

With a slight modification of the method above, we can apply arbitrary set functions to columns/rows of a nested association:

```
ClearAll[rowColumnMap]

rowColumnMap[rc : "Row" | "Column" | Automatic : "Column", 
  func_ : Ordering @* Ordering] :=
   (rc /. {"Row" -> Transpose, "Column" | Automatic -> Identity}) @*
   Transpose @*
   Map[Apply[AssociationThread] @* 
      Through @*{Keys, func @* Values} @*
      DeleteMissing] @*
  (rc /. {"Row" -> Identity, "Column" | Automatic -> Transpose}) @* 
  Dataset
```

***Examples:***

```
examples1 = {"Dataset@dt",
   "rowColumnMap[]@dt",
   "rowColumnMap[Automatic,Ordering@*Reverse@*Ordering]@dt",
   "rowColumnMap[\"Column\", Accumulate]@dt",
   "rowColumnMap[\"Column\", Prepend[0]@*Differences]@dt",
   "rowColumnMap[\"Column\", Prepend[Missing[_]]@*Ratios]@dt"};

Grid[Partition[Labeled[ToExpression@#, #, Top] & /@ examples1, 2], 
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

```
examples2 = {"Dataset@dt",
   "rowColumnMap[\"Row\"]@dt",
   "rowColumnMap[\"Row\",Ordering@*Reverse@*Ordering]@dt",
   "rowColumnMap[\"Row\", Accumulate]@dt",
   "rowColumnMap[\"Row\", Prepend[0]@*Differences]@dt",
   "rowColumnMap[\"Row\", Prepend[Missing[_]]@*Ratios]@dt"};

Grid[Partition[Labeled[ToExpression@#, #, Top] & /@ examples2, 2], 
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Love how you handled the `Missing` data point here

Comment: Thanks @kglr, beautiful and instructive

Answer (score 2):

**This is a solution that avoids using `Dataset`**

### EDIT:  New solution

After some thought I realised we can make then solution more elegant by properly defining our ranking function to handle `Missing` data. I have left my old answer below as my train of thought might be useful.

```
rank2[list_] := <|AssociationThread[Keys@list, Ordering@Ordering@list],Select[list, MissingQ]|>;
```

The solution:

```
Transpose[rank2 /@ Transpose@dt];

Dataset[%]
```

### [image]

### Old answer:

**Helper Functions**

*Credit to @Sjoerd C. de Vries for this [rank function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33151/ranking-a-vector-containing-ties) which I use a lot.*

Ranking function to apply:

```
rank[list_] := (Ordering@Ordering@list + Reverse@Ordering@Ordering@Reverse@list)/2;
```

Applying functions to an association removes the keys. This adds the keys back in

```
remakeAssociation[keys_, values_] := AssociationThread[keys, #] & /@ values;
```

The `rank` function has no error handling for `Missing[_]` (it will return a number). This function looks for the positions of the `Missing[]` from `dt` and places it back in.

```
replaceBadData[endData_, startData_, badDataPoint_] := 
    ReplacePart[endData, Position[startData, badDataPoint] -> badDataPoint];
```

**Solution**

```
solutionWithBadData = Transpose@remakeAssociation[Keys@dt, rank /@ Transpose@dt];
solution = replaceBadData[solutionWithBadData , dt, Missing[_]]

(*

<|
"fra" -> <|"19" -> 5, "20" -> 5, "21" -> 4, "22" -> 1|>, 
 "gre" -> <|"19" -> 2, "20" -> 1, "21" -> 1, "22" -> 4|>, 
 "ita" -> <|"19" -> 3, "20" -> 3, "21" -> 3, "22" -> 3|>, 
 "por" -> <|"19" -> 1, "20" -> 4, "21" -> 2, "22" -> 2|>, 
 "spa" -> <|"19" -> 4, "20" -> 2, "21" -> 5, "22" -> Missing[_]|>
|>

*)
```

and `Dataset` to make it pretty

```
Dataset[solution]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Intro, also very nice